# How to disable sending double emails to customer aftre registration in magento?

Tags: php, email, magento

After registration customer recieve email imforming about 10% off. It works fine but that email is dubled. The same email is sending twice times. 
Swiching off Mailchimp doesn't resolve that problem so probably it is not in configuration.
Probably two emails modules capture event but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Magento does not have a standard module to send email with promotions on customer registration. You either installed a custom module for this or had someone develop it for you.

Comment: after using   $emailTemplate->send($customerData['email'], $customerData['firstname'] . ' ' . $customerData['lastname'], $emailTemplateVariables);  recieve two emails

Comment: And are you sure that's the only place where the email sending functionality is implemented? Try commenting that code out and see if the customers receives an email or not.

Comment: I am almost sure. When I disable  $emailTemplate method, emails are not sending at all.